# BJT Transistor Open/Low or variable load behavior

Tags: transistors, bjt

How does a BJT react when saturating the base with a very low collector current? For example, 10 mA into the base of a 2n2222a with a collector current of 20 mA in a common collector setup. Will the base forward drop increase or decrease, or otherwise overheat, or anything else?

What about variable loads, like a led controller that may go from 10% to 100% PWM . Would this cause any unwanted behavior?

Comment: Ib current is a function of a Vbe voltage. Thus, if Ib increases the Vbe will also increase. And for "low frequency" Ib > Ic in saturation is not a problem.

Comment: I think you should show your circuit to avoid ambiguity.